# Distribution Provisioning Profile not showing up in code signing identity selection in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, appstore-approval, provisioning, xcodebuild

I have followed all steps carefully mentioned in the iOS provisioning portal. The biggest problem is that those steps are not updated to the latest version of XCode.

In Xcode's organizer, the distribution profile is showing up in Library>Provisioning profiles. But when I go to iPod Touch > Provisioning profiles, it's not there. (I don't know if this information is relevant, just mentioned to make sure I don't miss anything).

To distribute the app with this new provisioning profile, I have to change the Code Sign Identity in the app configuration to this distribution provisioning profile but I can't see it anywhere in the menu. It's just not there, where is it? How can I can build my app with this distribution provisioning profile?

I did everything from beginning for at least 2 times. Still no success.

Is there any step by step tutorial to do this in XCode 4? Please help! I am going insane.

Comment: same problem here, any solutions on this?

Comment: This might be a solution for some: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897126/provisioning-profiles-in-xcode-5

Answer (score 1):

In the Navigator view, select your project name, then go to Build Settings for your target.  In the drop-down under Code Signing Identity, select the developer identity you want to build with...if you have multiple provisioning profiles, select the developer identity under the appropriate provision you want to use.  You can see all your provisioning profiles in this drop-down.

If you cannot select a developer identity under the provision you want to use, you might check your Bundle identifier in your Info.plist.

Make sure your iPod Touch's UDID is added to your provisioning profile as well.

Comment: I cannot select the distributor provision that I created in the provisional portal. How can I distribute apps? I am so confused.

Comment: When you created your distribution provisioning profile, did you select the appropriate App ID?  Do you have a distribution certificate?  Try looking here: http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action 

When you're ready to distribute your app, your distribution profile shouldn't install on your device.  When you archive, your app, you can then proceed to Organizer, select the archived application build, then hit the Submit button.

Comment: Bleech... What a miserable process.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by switching targets.  After clicking on the blue project icon in the project navigator, there are 2 rows with thin icons in the main viewing area.  Make sure your whole project (the BLUE icon) is selected in the second row, not just the main target (the drafting tools icon).

So this:
[image: Correct configuration for selecting distribution profile]

Not this:
[image: Incorrect configuration for selecting distribution profile]

Comment: Saved me a lot of time!