# Provisioning Profiles in XCode 5

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, xcode5

I started using XCode 5 today and found when trying to archive a project for ad-hoc distribution that the provisioning profiles I was presented with did not include one I had recently created, but did include one that I had deleted. I checked the list of profiles in my Organizer for that device, and that list was OK and included the recent one that I had downloaded.

So my question is, what's going on here. Where's my profiles?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found the answer by following a clue here on this site on a related subject. You have to go into XCode | Preferences | Accounts | View Details. There you will see the (old) list. Hit the refresh button. That will download an updated list.

Now when I go to distribute my archive ad-hoc, I get the refreshed list of profiles.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. My ad-hoc Provisioning Profile is not available when I try to sign for distribution. However, it is available in XCode | Preferences | Accounts | View Details. How do I make it available for distribution?

Comment: sometimes it takes a while though (for some reason the 'propagation' of the provision profile takes a while.. especially with apple's notoriously slow servers).. so keep on clicking the refresh button, if it doesn't show up.. just work on something else until the next day.. i sometimes had to wait that long

Comment: Nice of them to make it more hidden like that instead of having, you know, a refresh button in the provisioning profiles view.

Comment: I'll try this, because I have duplicate Ad Hoc profiles, and I want to make sure I code sign with the latest version (i.e., the most devices included).

Answer (score 2):

I found out that downloading and manually adding it by double clicking works fine as well. Don't have to wait all day ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by millport sorted things out for me. What you need to do also though is to choose the profile you're working with and before downloading chooose 'edit' and choose to include those of your registered devices that you want to use as new added devices are not automatically included in your profiles