# No provisioning for the executable -again

Tags: xcode

I know its been asked so many times, and i have read them all, but i just can't find any solution to my specific problem.

The app is in release mode, it has the `distribution and development provisioning` generated , and dragged to Xcode.

In xcode , the `code signing` does show me that distribution of that app to choose, so if i choose dev provisioning it works, if i choose distribution (in the "release") and run on device i get :

```
A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
```

The app name is good, the bundle identifier also , i just can't do nothing . no idea where to go from here ,or even how to find the problem. what should i see in the organizer ?

Does the `com.company.A` , need to be with the exact app name **A**  also ? (app name has space anyway,so i guess they shouldn't even spelled the same)
(its not my first app, so certificates probably ok).

i have read this, and more :
[A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found... (again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727655/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-again)

nothing helped .

Comment: You can try this, delete the existing provisioning and download and install it again from Apple Account.

Comment: how do i delete them? i was trying to delete the development one from the organizer, than to drag it again to Xcode, but its not appear again in the organizer( there is no refresh button for me... )

Comment: To delete the provisioning from Organiser, just right click on the profile -> Delete Profile. To add provisioning profile, just double click on it, it will ask from you to install.

Comment: ok its there again after i deleted it, but still not working, i think that the problem is with the distribution file, so deleting the development provisioning is not helpful anyway. where can i find the distribution one? its not in the organizer..

Comment: Both development and distribution are on the same list. If it's not showing means you have not installed it. Download the fresh profile from Apple Account and install. And then select the provisioning profile in Build Settings of Xcode. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: i don't think that both has to be there. actually i have 6 apps at the store, and all the developments provisionings are there ( in the organizer provisioning) and not even 1 distribution file. and they all works, so i guess only dev files are in there. anyway is not my first time,  you just have to click the distribution file , thats it. i did in 3 times, and its not there/work.

Comment: In the organizer , under provisioning profiles, do you need to have the the name of the development profile you gave it, or also something like that: iOS team provisioning profile com.company.appname   ?? because i have for a few apps that sentence also , and others not ...

Comment: They will have the same name, that you gave them while creating it. You can match it with your provisioning profiles in your Apple Account.

Comment: NO. I DONT GET IT. please explain to me. in the apple portal, i have created 2 files, dev and distribution. each has its name, appDev, and appDis , i have download both, click them , and in the organizer i can see only the appDev file, no appDis file . and as i just said, no other app has the appDis file in there, and all of the rest are works under the distribution . another thing that let me know that the distribution is there, is because i can see it in the code signing list. so what am i missing here? can you be more specific,  please ?

Comment: Which Xcode version you are using?

Comment: Please check in Xcode Preferences > Accounts:

Comment: check what ?? if you don't want to answer thats ok, but if you do, please be more specific, please. because i am starting to guess for every little information you write here.

Comment: Refer to these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897126/provisioning-profiles-in-xcode-5 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041267/provisioning-profiles-menu-item-missing-from-xcode-5

Comment: ok i have refresh it, but what it has to do with the missing file ? i still get the same message about the missing provisioning,

Comment: wait, if you put your app in distribution, in the code signing , should it work anyway ? or do you set it to distribution just when you want to upload the app to the store ?

Comment: if you are getting missing profile, it means that the profile is not installed or you have selected the old profile in xcode project. Install the new one and select it from the list again in build settings.

Comment: Second options is to check for the valid certificate for the profile, if you dont have valid certificate for the profile it will be inactive.

Comment: i have done what you said for 10 times. thanks anyway.